# JProgressBar displaying weird orang wave

Tags: java, swing, jprogressbar, nimbus

I am using JProgressBar to display a progress bar on my frame. The progress bar is set to indeterminate mode as i dont know when the task will end. Instead of displaying the normal progress bar a wierd orange wave is displayed.
[image: 1]

The wave keeps moving when the task is running. After it has ended the value is set to 100 and it displays it in the form or orange blocks(**which are also moving**!). I am using the following code to display the progress bar

```
Container content = this.getContentPane();
content.setLayout(null);    
prog = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
prog.setValue(0);
prog.setStringPainted(true);
Dimension preferredSize;
preferredSize=new Dimension();
preferredSize.width=300;
preferredSize.height=15;
prog.setPreferredSize(preferredSize);
content.add(prog);
Insets insets = content.getInsets();
Dimension size;
size = prog.getPreferredSize();
prog.setBounds(30+insets.left, 180+insets.top, size.width, size.height);
```

How do i change it back to the normal progress bar?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, just about JFrame and JProgressBar, maybe could be important what LookandFeel is used

Comment: That looks like the normal progress bar for the Nimbus Look-and-feel

Comment: should it be moving even after its value is set to 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't look deep into it, but it might be a bug of Nimbus LaF.
Anyway, in order for the orange blocks to stop moving (when its value is set to 100), you also seem to need to call:

```
prog.setIndeterminate(false);
```

If you want to "automate" this, you could subclass JProgressBar, e.g.:

```
prog = new JProgressBar(0, 100) {
    public void setValue(int newValue) {
        super.setValue(newValue);
        if (newValue >= this.getMaximum()) {
            this.setIndeterminate(false);
        }
    }
};
prog.setValue(0);
...
```